# Convert UTM or Lat Lng to MGRS (Military Grid Reference System)

Tags: coordinate-systems

Currently I'm working on my GIS application and I require MGRS coordinates. I have the lat long and UTM coordinates of any point on my map but I need help converting those to MGRS.

I don't know where to start from. Please Guide me.

Comment: I would start by taking some random location (let's say Stockholm, Sweden) and figuring out the coordinates in both systems.

Comment: This web page https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html has javascript code for conversion, as well as links to documentation and test cases.  (I have not tried it out.)